# How to filter names on Wordpress comments?

Tags: wordpress

I would like to filter names on my comments section.

For example, if a user type a name listed on my black-list, the comment will not be saved or will be marked as spam. Any idea on where to start or if it's even possible?

Comment: _"Any idea on where to start"_ - go check the WP docs to see what kind of hooks are available around posting/saving of a new comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know if this is what you're looking for, but Wordpress already has a plugin for Spam protection called [Askimet](https://akismet.com/) Just check if you have it installed in your system.

Comment: Excellent. This is exactly what I need. All I had to do is to set a list of terms to be blocked on Wordpress dashboard (at Discussion section). I didn't knew Askimet also had this feature. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Yes [Askimet](https://akismet.com/) is a good option, but if some one want to do it manually ( for some reason ) you can use `wp_insert_comment` for this purpose.

do something like this.

```
function check_comment_inserted( $comment_id, $comment_object ) {
    /**
     *  Here is the list of properties, that comment_object carrying 
     *      
     *  $comment_object->comment_ID": "29",
     *  $comment_object->comment_post_ID": "1",
     *  $comment_object->comment_author": "Sark",
     *  $comment_object->comment_author_email": "mycholan@ymail.com",
     *  $comment_object->comment_author_url": "http:\\/\\/sarkware.com",
     *  $comment_object->comment_author_IP": "::1",
     *  $comment_object->comment_date": "2016-05-19 20:27:53",
     *  $comment_object->comment_date_gmt": "2016-05-19 20:27:53",
     *  $comment_object->comment_content": "Fifth comment",
     *  $comment_object->comment_karma": "0",
     *  $comment_object->comment_approved": "0",
     *  $comment_object->comment_agent": "Mozilla\\/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit\\/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome\\/50.0.2661.87 Safari\\/537.36 OPR\\/37.0.2178.32",
     *  $comment_object->comment_type": "",
     *  $comment_object->comment_parent": "0",
     *  $comment_object->user_id": "0"
    **/

    $block_list = array( 'name1', 'name2', 'name3', 'name4' );

    foreach( $block_list as $name ) {
        if ( stripos( $comment_object->comment_content, $name ) !== false ) {
            // now set this comment status
            // Valid comment status : 'hold', 'approve', 'spam', or 'trash'
            wp_set_comment_status( $comment_id, "spam" );
            break;
        }
    }   
}
add_action( 'wp_insert_comment', 'check_comment_inserted', 99, 2 );
```

Comment: Interesting! Always good to have a plugin independent option.